# How to insert into a table with a unique identity INT column as primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To insert into a table with the next integer ID value, would it look something like this?

```
DECLARE @RoomID INT
SELECT @RoomID = (SELECT count(*) FROM [dbo].[Rooms])
SELECT @RoomID = SELECT @RoomID + 1

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rooms]
           ([RoomID], 
            [RoomType], 
            [Description], 
            [DateCreated], 
            [IsActive])
     VALUES
           (@RoomID, 
            2,  
            N'Room Description X', 
            CONVERT(DateTime2, getdate()),
            1)
```

Comment: Why not use an `identity` column?

Comment: Isn't SCOPE_IDENTITY() set after an insert?

Comment: Are you asking can you use `scope_identity()` to get the last value inserted into an `identity` column? If so then yes. If you were asking something else then I'm not following.

Comment: You're asking for trouble if you roll you own unique identifier.

Comment: And the `count` may not be the `max`. What happens if row `13` was deleted last week? Aside: Someone must be getting paid by the `select`. Why not `set @RoomId += 1;` or `select @RoomId = Count(*) from dbo.Rooms;`? And the [conversion[(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) from `DateTime` to `DateTime2` will be done implicitly, if it is needed at all.

Comment: just skip RoomID column and sql will insert the next id for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to force a specific number into a column that is an identity column you have to use the command `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table_name OFF` and turn it back on after your done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql

2. If you just want to insert data into the table, you skip the column and SQL Server will insert it for you.

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rooms]
               ( 
                [RoomType], 
                [Description], 
                [DateCreated], 
                [IsActive])
         VALUES
               (
                2,  
                N'Room Description X', 
                CONVERT(DateTime2, getdate()),
                1)
```

Comment: @Bill which part of this answer solved your problem? I'm just trying to work out what your actual question was.

Comment: @DaleK it's pretty clear: How to insert into a table with a unique identity int column as primary key?

Comment: Not only is the question unclear, because while does mention identity in the title, identity is not mentioned again in the question. But also OP is attempting to calculate it themselves - which would normally indicate its not an identity column. And as your answer is actually 2 answers I am interested to know which one helped out the OP.

Comment: @DaleK it is only unclear to you because you are a seasoned dev. The question is perfectly clear for a new users. If you rewrite it for pro, it would be useless. We are not writing answers for the OP only but for anyone there after who will find this question. Taking a guess based on his questions. OP will need to use Option one for Dataload where he needs to force exact values, and use  option 2 for simple insert where the number is the next it.